# SkyDrive API file upload using REST

Tags: .net, api, rest, onedrive

I'm testing SkyDrive's API using the following code:

```
Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=" & Me.ACCESS_TOKEN), HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest.Method = "POST"
    webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x"
    webRequest.KeepAlive = True
    webRequest.Timeout = 80000
    Using streamWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream())
      streamWriter.Write("--A300x\r\n")
      streamWriter.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""HelloWorld.txt""\r\n")
      streamWriter.Write("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n")
      streamWriter.Write("\r\n")
      streamWriter.Write("vooo")
      streamWriter.Write("\r\n")
      streamWriter.Write("--A300x--\r\n")
      streamWriter.Close()
    End Using
    ' response
    Using webResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(webRequest, HttpWebRequest).GetResponse()
      If webResponse.StatusCode() = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Using streamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
          Throw New Exception(streamReader.ReadToEnd())
          streamReader.Close()
        End Using
      End If
      webResponse.Close()
    End Using
```

Getting bad request (400). Access token and URL are verified & valid. any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the response body (or use Fiddler to do the same) you'll find a JSON-formatted error message that explains exactly where the problem lies. My first guess is that the folder **skydrive** doesn't exist for this target user.

Answer (score 2):

I've used following method to upload files to Skydrive. Works ok, as for me.

```
 public void uploadFile(string ParentFolderID, string FileName)
    {
        string uri = String.Format(SkyDriveHelper.BaseURI + ParentFolderID + "/files"+"?access_token=" + account.accessInfo.access_token);
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x");
            Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(uri);

            //writing start boundary
            requestStream.Write("--A300x\r\n".ToByteArray(), 0, "--A300x\r\n".Count());

            //writing body headers
            string header1 = String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{0}\"\r\n", FileName);
            requestStream.Write(header1.ToByteArray(), 0, header1.Count());
            string header2 = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
            requestStream.Write(header2.ToByteArray(), 0, header2.Count());
            requestStream.Write("\r\n".ToByteArray(), 0, "\r\n".Count());

            //writing body - WRITE BYTES HERE 
            requestStream.Write("HelloWorld".ToByteArray(), 0, "HelloWorld".Count());

            //writing finish boundary
            requestStream.Write("\r\n\r\n".ToByteArray(), 0, "\r\n\r\n".Count());
            requestStream.Write("--A300x\r\n".ToByteArray(), 0, "--A300x\r\n".Count());
            requestStream.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Download Error:" + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: nothing wrong, this routine upload file to skydrive. Write your file bytes after the comment //writing body.